# If $\gamma(b)$ is not conjugate to $\gamma(a)$ along $\gamma$. Show that $I(V, V)=I(J, J)$ if and only if $V=J .$

Tags: solution-verification, riemannian-geometry

**Exercice 10-12 (Introduction to Riemannian Geometry, Lee):**

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. Suppose $\gamma:[a, b] \rightarrow M$ is a unitspeed geodesic segment with no interior conjugate points, $J$ is a normal Jacobi field along $\gamma$, and $V$ is any other piecewise smooth normal vector field along $\gamma$ such that $V(a)=J(a)$ and $V(b)=J(b)$.

(a) Show that $I(V, V) \geq I(J, J)$.

(b) Now assume in addition that $\gamma(b)$ is not conjugate to $\gamma(a)$ along $\gamma$. Show that $I(V, V)=I(J, J)$ if and only if $V=J .$

---

I think that if $\gamma$ has no interior conjugate points then it minimize the distance(!). Let $V$ be a proper and normal field along $\gamma$, then
$I(V,V) \geqslant 0$, or $I(J,J)=0$(since it's a Jacobi field), then $$I(V,V) \geqslant I(J,J)$$
For the second question, suppose that $I(V,V)=I(J,J)$ and $V\not =J$
Then if V is proper, $V(a)=J(a)=0$ and $V(b)=J(b)=0$. Since $J(a)=J(b)=0$ then $J=0$ everywhere then $I(V,V)=0$ and $V\not =0$, so $V$ is a Jacobi field and hence $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are two conjugate points which contradicts our hypothesis !
I don't really know is this is true or not, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I think that if γ has no interior conjugate points then it minimize the distance": this is false. The flat torus is a counter-example. The fact there is no conjugate points along $\gamma$ says that there cannot exist a smooth family of geodesics joining $p$ and $q$ in a neighbourhood of $\gamma$, unless the constant family.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your argument. As @Didier commented, it does not follow from the absence of conjugate points that $\gamma$ is length-minimizing. More importantly, most of your claims about $I(V,V)$ and $I(J,J)$ would be justified if $V$ and $J$ were proper (i.e., vanishing at the endpoints), but there's no such assumption in the problem statement.

BTW, in case anyone wants to look this up in the book, this is ***Problem 10-12***, not Exercise 10.12. The problems are at the ends of the chapters, while exercises are incorporated into the text of the chapters.